# how to have google sites pages display things specific to the currently logged in user

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-sites

I've been wondering for a while if I can have google sites pages display things specific to the currently logged in user.  I keep googling for a solution, but never come up with anything conclusive.

Basically I use Google sites for my university class websites.  I'd love it if I could display things specific to an individual student, such as, you have completed homeworks 1,2 and 3 - now it's time to work on homework number 4

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've search in Google and found this:

> You can use Page-level permissions to display certain pages to certain
>   users.  You can use Google Apps Script to detect the signed in user
>   too, but what you could display in Google Apps Script is limited. I'd
>   go for Page-level permissions.

([Link to that post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/lOCVf1aJZNo) on Google community support site.)

I think this is a good start for you.

Comment: thanks - that is a good start - what I really need now is an example pulling spreadsheet data in a google site ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264255/example-display-of-google-spreadsheet-data-in-google-site-via-google-apps-script