# Example display of Google Spreadsheet data in Google site via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I see that some people are trying to grab data from google spreadsheets via google apps script to stick in their google sites:

[How to access data on different Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727975/how-to-access-data-on-different-google-spreadsheet-through-google-apps-script)

I could bash away at code snippets, but I don't suppose anyone has got a working example anywhere?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: -1 really? seems like a reasonable question to me - I always like to start from a working example ...

Comment: in particular the existing examples on google all seem to assume that a spreadsheet script is running from within a spreadsheet itself - it's not clear how one points to a particular spreadsheet from a script hosted in a google site ...

Comment: Hey buddy, I'm new too, but some advice I have on asking questions is to provide some example of code you've tried already. Asking for working examples before trying something on your own just means folks are coding for you, which isn't cool. SO is pretty great, right?

Comment: point taken, but the GAS team are pointing people to StackOverflow as their support "forum".  When Google are providing a system like GAS and have lots of examples, but I can't find the right kind of example in their site, can I not ask if there is one that I have missed?  It may also be that it's actually not possible.  Rather than bash away for hours to discover something is not possible, can't I ask if there is a working example of something?  I've been programming 30 years and teach computer science and tell all my students if you can find a working example, that's golden.

Comment: I think there is a conflict between the kinds of questions I want to ask the Google GAS team and the questions I would ask of the community, but the Google GAS team are not providing an independent forum and my direct questions to them go unanswered.  As you will see from the answer I left below I shared the code that I eventually got to work.  See, me contributing to the community. If I can't ask for help finding working examples I think that's a shame.  Maybe I shouldn't ask on StackOverflow, but the GAS team aren't leaving me much of a choice ...

Comment: This question is asking for external resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was looking for something like this:

https://sites.google.com/site/testappscript2/

At the moment I don't think you'll see anything if you are not logged in to Google, but if you are then it might show this:

Welcome, don't know your name, but if you add your details here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq72y9iq5_1UdG5LR0tCVTRXOVQtbkNLR1Q3eE5MR0E#gid=0
I could tell you your next assignment

if your google mail is in the spreadsheet it will show a personalized message.

My idea is to manage what a student sees in a Google site for a course depending on how the instructor has updated the students data in an online spreadsheet, so the student can see which assignments they've completed - what they have to do next, and possibly even their grades ...

Comment: This doesn't show how it was made, it doesn't include any programming stuff.